# I18n.t Translation Missing Default Value Nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, rails-i18n

So I know how return a default value if I get "translation missing:" when reading a yaml file.

```
some = I18n.t("something.something_else", default: "value")
```

But how do I do that in the Ruby way if I want the default value to be nil? I know I can regex and match for "translation missing:" from the variable some and if it matches, I would have it assign to nil. But what I wanted to do is have

```
some = I18n.t("something.something_else", default: nil)
```

But it just returned translation missing for me. Does anyone know a good way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`:default` can't be nil. Setting the value to `nil` is equivalent to not set the option at all.

However, since the gem seems to [only check whether the key is nil or not](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/v0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb#L33-L34), you can try to pass an empty string as a default value. It is possible the `translate` method will return an empty string in case of a missing translation.

```
some = I18n.t("something.something_else", default: "")
```

I believe this is the closer solution you can get, unless you define your custom `translate` method that internally lookups the presence of the key and returns nil if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: So basically there is no good way to return nil when it is translation missing. Thanks for the answer. I can't quite understand why. Is that an implementation feature? Or just how the code was written up to be?

Comment: You could add a check for presence so that you are sure to get a translated string or nil back:

`some = I18n.t("something.something_else", default: "").presence`

Answer (score 8):

Try this `some = I18n.t!("something.something_else") rescue nil`

Ok, it's a bad practice to perform a `rescue nil` but, it's short and cute :)

You can do something like this

```
def translate(key)
  I18n.t!(key)
rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
  nil
end
```

Then...

`some = translate("something.something_else")`

Comment: This is not very efficient for an application with a large number of strings as raising an exception and rescuing it has a noticeable cost at interpreter level. The best solution would be to check for the existence of the key without triggering the exception.

Comment: I think is a decision... If this code affects considerably the performance in the context used, I'm agree with you.